# Symfony2 create and update fields using entity generator wizard

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create some entities with the symfony2 entity generator wizard:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

What I want is to have created_at and updated_at fields on this one entity. I know that symfony2 takes care of those fields, but I wanted to create using the wizard generator. Is it possible? If so, how to I create them? Or do I have to create the entity and then update it through the code to have these fields?

Thanks in advance.
CR

Answer (score 1):

By default symfony2 has no automagically created and updated fields

in the generator choose `createdAt` and `datetime` you need to set those fields manually.

Or You can use [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle). This describes in [symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html). It contains [Timestampable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md) behavior.

```
/**
 * @var datetime $created
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var datetime $updated
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $updated;
```

it also makes sense to have an AbstractEntity with those fields as u need them for most entities which can simply extend the AbstractEntity